# Multi-level water storage tanks

Tags: water, water-tank

Original water tank is one meter above ground and one meter in ground where the suction pipe is located. It fills with float valve approx. 80cm above ground. A new tank has been added sitting on the ground and is 2.5m tall. They both fill from a common 1 1/2” pipe. Above ground tank is manual shut off.
When lower tank needs water, manual shut off is opened and water siphons from new tank to old (water inlet/outlet enters new tank to 8” above floor). Water siphoning stops when new water tank level is the same as inlet into original tank.

How to automatically overcome the siphon level to keep putting water into lower (original) tank to the level of inlet/outlet pipe in new above ground tank?

Comment: I don't understand. You may be using "siphon" inappropriately at times when you simply mean "drain". A diagram may help.

Comment: It is a siphon. Main water comes in to both tanks - when full it is shut off. As the float valve lowers in the original tank it pulls in water from the new tank via siphoning.

Comment: Ok. A diagram showing the relative positions of the various valves and floats would really help us out.